# Change text color of div element text on mouse over and mouse out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want change the Text color on mouse hover and mouse out.Since inside number of div elements, it is not working.Please help if anything.

```
<div class="u860" id="u860" style="top: 0px;">
    <div id="u860_rtf">
        <p style="text-align: left;" id="cache228">
        <a class="music" href="AppLauncher_TradeSearch">
            <span class="test1" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11px; 
                font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; 
                color: rgb(37, 80, 99);" id="cache229">Different</span>
        </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Color of "Different" should change on over and out.

Comment: share what you have already tried? on hover of which element you want to change the color

Comment: You really need jQuery for `:hover`? :O @ArunPJohny Close

Comment: Would people get mad if I made a super confusing long jQuery script and left him with that answer for this.... Just because its funny :D

Comment: I tried onMouseover event , that does not seem to work.Is CSS enough to change text color in above?

Comment: Did my answer reply to your question?

Answer (score 7):

**The best solution in these cases is to use CSS**,

```
.test1:hover{
    color:red !important;
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VnnW9/1/)

less good is to add a class, like:

```
$('.test1').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('newColor');
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass('newColor');
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VnnW9/2/)**

and the last option:

```
$('.test1').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
},
function () {
    $(this).css('color', 'rgb(37, 80, 99)');
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VnnW9/)**

Comment: why the best is to use css and the last is using .css method?

Answer (score 3):

Try this css:

```
.u860:hover a, .u860:hover span {
    color:red !important;
}
```

you are using style in span, so you have to use !important.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wRB7g/)

Comment: Just for my curiosity, can you make it work without the !important?

Comment: TO: Nathan Lee. I think you have to use !important becouse if you use styl atribute in tag it is more then atribute in css files, that is reason for using !important for span element in this case.

Comment: TO: Hmnshu, I try it in IE8 (windows 7) and it works, but what do you use as operation system?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $(".u860").mouseover(function(){
    $(".u860").css("background-color","cyan");
  });$(".u860").mouseout(function(){
    $(".u860").css("background-color","gray");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emdhie/WV5v6/

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hmnshu i didn't see the code for hover css..
Try this one.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <style>
   span{
        font-family: Calibri; 
        font-size: 11px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-style: normal; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: rgb(37, 80, 99);
       }
  span:hover{
       color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
       }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="u860" id="u860" style="top: 0px;">
  <div id="u860_rtf">
   <p style="text-align: left;" id="cache228">
    <a class="music" href="AppLauncher_TradeSearch">
      <span class="test1"  id="cache229">Different</span>
    </a>
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```